# How to print multiple combinations of arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to "play" a made up game where it prints a combination of numbers from 1-20 with a combination of heads or tails and rock, paper, scissor. For example (output):

1 of Rock Tails

1 of Paper Heads

3 of Scissors Heads

15 of Paper Tails

15 of Rock Heads

The user is given a menu where they can choose to sort by ID or sort by Value. I think my code is correct, but my problem comes when I enter "2". The program is supposed to print combinations until it gets to "20 of Rock/Paper/Scissor Head/Tails". It doesn't matter if it repeats, as long as it stops at 20. How can I do this? Right now it is only printing one combination when I enter "2" on my menu.

```
    class Card:
        def __init__(self, id=0):
            self.id = id
            self.value = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
                          "15", "16", "17", "18","19", "20"]
            self.paw = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
            self.coin = ["Heads", "Tails"]
            k = 0

            for v in self.value:
                for p in self.paw:
                    for c in self.coin:
                        if k == self.id:
                            self.value = v
                            self.paw = p
                            self.coin = c
                        k += 1

        def __str__(self):
            return self.value + " of " + self.paw + " " + self.coin
    class Deck:
        def __init__(self):
            self.value = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
                         "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
            self.paw = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
            self.coin = ["Heads", "Tails"]
            self.deck = []
            for i in range(len(self.value) * len(self.paw) * len(self.coin)):
                self.deck.append(Card(i))

    def convertCardToValue(Cardvalue, Cardpaw, Cardcoin):
        maxCardValue = 20
        paw = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        coin = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        return 2 * ((Cardvalue - 1) + (maxCardValue * paw.index(Cardpaw))) + \
               coin.index(Cardcoin)

    def main():

        choice = '0'
        while choice == '0':
            print("Welcome to the Gronky Deck Checker!")
            print("1) Sort by Value")
            print("2) Sort by ID")
            print("3) Find Card")
            print("4) New Hand")
            print("5) Quit")

            choice = input("Please make a selection: ")

        if choice == "5":
            print("Thanks for Playing!")
        elif choice == "4":
            pass
        elif choice == "3":
            pass
        elif choice == "2":
            myCard = Card(12)
            print(myCard)
        elif choice == "1":
            myDeck = Deck()
            print(myDeck)
        else:
            print("I don't understand your choice.")
    main()
```

Comment: I just run a quick test, it seems like k == 2 only once so only one value is print when id = 2
I still do not understand what do you want when input is 2 ?

Comment: How can I solve that?

Comment: do you mean you want all combination of value, paw, coin been print when input == 2 ? @User1020

Comment: 30 shuffled values. For example: 1 of Rock Heads, 3 of Scissors Heads, 7 of Rock Tails... etc. The numbers have to be in order from 1-20, but they don't have to be 1,2,3,4,5. They could be 2,5,6,10,10,10,11,11,16,16... etc until 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print 30 combination of card when input is 2

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, id=0):
        self.id = id
        self.value = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
                      "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
        self.paw = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        self.coin = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        k = 0

        for v in self.value:
            for p in self.paw:
                for c in self.coin:
                    if k == self.id:
                        self.value = v
                        self.paw = p
                        self.coin = c
                    k += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value + " of " + self.paw + " " + self.coin


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
                      "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
        self.paw = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        self.coin = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        self.deck = []
        for i in range(len(self.value) * len(self.paw) * len(self.coin)):
            self.deck.append(Card(i))


def convertCardToValue(Cardvalue, Cardpaw, Cardcoin):
    maxCardValue = 20
    paw = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    coin = ["Heads", "Tails"]
    return 2 * ((Cardvalue - 1) + (maxCardValue * paw.index(Cardpaw))) + \
           coin.index(Cardcoin)


def main():
    choice = '0'
    while choice == '0':
        print("Welcome to the Gronky Deck Checker!")
        print("1) Sort by Value")
        print("2) Sort by ID")
        print("3) Find Card")
        print("4) New Hand")
        print("5) Quit")

        choice = input("Please make a selection: ")

    if choice == "5":
        print("Thanks for Playing!")
    elif choice == "4":
        pass
    elif choice == "3":
        pass
    elif choice == "2":
        start_id = 0
        myCard = Card(start_id)
        while isinstance(myCard.value, str) and int(myCard.value) < 21:
            print(myCard)
            start_id += random.randint(1,20)
            myCard = Card(start_id)
        if isinstance(myCard.value , list) or int(myCard.value) != 20:
            myCard = Card(119)
            print(myCard)
    elif choice == "1":
        myDeck = Deck()
        print(myDeck)
    else:
        print("I don't understand your choice.")
```

each myCard object is only assigned to 1 set of combinations, so if you want 30, run it 30 times

Comment: But it never passes from 6. Actually, it doesn't matter how many numbers it prints it can print 50, but it needs to stop at 20. 1,1,1,3,4,4,7,7,7,7,12,12,14, 17, 19,19, 20 [STOP].

Comment: do you mean keep generate myCard object with random increase id until id reach 20 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Comment: Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Thank you! It does reach 20, the only thing is that it increases by one number everytime instead of randomly increasing. E.g., 1,3,7,8,10,11,13,15,18,20. Right now it increases like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11... etc.